# bash scripting key value array in "etc/passwd" file

Tags: shell-script, bash-array

I want my `/etc/passwd` file to be as an array like this

[user_id] => [home_directory]

e.g.

```
[0]      =>  "/root"
[1000]   =>  "/home/user1"
[1001]   =>  "/home/user2"
```

so after that, I can set a condition that if user_id is greater than 999 (it mean usual users) then check if in `.htaccess file` of its directory the values of `memory_limit` and `display_errors` are exists or not.

for the aforesaid goal, I ran the command bellow

`cat   /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{print $4,$6}'`

it shows all

`user_id       home_directory`

but I don't know how to put them in the array I mentioned before.

because some users in `/etc/passwd` have no home directory my array keys get incorrect values.

please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks Roraima, that really helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shell array

```
# Associative array p
declare -A p=()

# Populate the array (x is a placeholder that we otherwise ignore)
while IFS=: read -r x x uid x x home x
do
    p[$uid]=$home
done </etc/passwd

# Demonstrate the data
for uid in "${!p[@]}"
do
    printf "[%s]\t=> \"%s\"\n" "$uid" "${p[$uid]}"
done
```

Example output

```
[1000]  => "/home/pi"
[0]     => "/root"
[1]     => "/usr/sbin"
[33]    => "/var/www"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IFS=$'\n'  
user=( $(awk -F':' '{print $4}' /etc/passwd | tr '\n' ' ') )  
homeDir=( $(awk -F':' '{print $6}' /etc/passwd |tr '\n' ' '))  
unset IFS
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are
better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).